# Why my Temporary queue keeps vanishing when using MassTransit IRequestClient

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a .net core api with Masstransit 7.3.1. I have multiple IRequestClient in my controllers and my request client are injected as illustrated below.

```
private readonly IRequestClient<GetEntity> _getEntity;

public UserController(IRequestClient<GetEntity> getEntity) {
_getEntity = getEntity;
}
```

```
services.AddScoped(x => x.GetRequiredService<IBus>().CreateRequestClient<GetEntity>("queueName"));
```

```
public static IRequestClient<TRequest> CreateRequestClient<TRequest>(this IBus bus, string queueName, TimeSpan? requestTimeout = null) where TRequest : class
        {
            return Implementation.CreateRequestClient<TRequest>(bus, queueName, requestTimeout);
        }

public IRequestClient<TRequest> CreateRequestClient<TRequest>(IBus bus, string queueName, TimeSpan? requestTimeout = null) where TRequest : class
        {
            var timeout = requestTimeout ??  TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
            var serviceAdresse = bus.Address.Segments.Count() > 2 ? new Uri($"rabbitmq://{bus.Address.Host}{bus.Address.Segments[0]}{bus.Address.Segments[1]}{queueName}") : new Uri($"rabbitmq://{bus.Address.Host}{bus.Address.Segments[0]}{queueName}");
            var client = bus.CreateRequestClient<TRequest>(serviceAdresse, timeout);
            return client;
}
```

I have a consumer in another app whos responding to my requests.

```
 public class GetEntityConsumer : IConsumer<GetEntity>
    {
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<GetEntity> context)
        {
            await context.RespondAsync(new BaseResult());
        }
    }
```

When I start my api on IIS a temporary queue created on the first query and my api woks as intended for some time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZTDT.png)

But then the temporary queue disappears and only the exchange is left by with no binding. When it happens All my requests stop responding and all I got is timeouts exception, but the GetEntityConsumer is called and it’s responding. I can’t find my responses on RabbitMQ.
The time it takes vary some time Is one hour but mostly is a day.
The only i found is restarting the iis pool when it hapen but i need to find a solution.
I am not sure where is the problem maybe is my architecture or my configuration.

My RabbitMq version is 3.7.10

I tried to check the bus status when it happen in an action filter

```
 private bool IsBusStarted()
        {
            if (_busControl == null)
                return false;
            FieldInfo fieldInfo = _busControl.GetType().GetField("_busHandle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            var busBundle = fieldInfo.GetValue(_busControl);

            if (busBundle == null)
                return false;
            try
            {
                PropertyInfo prop = busBundle.GetType().GetProperty("Ready");
                MethodInfo getter = prop.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true);
                var result = getter.Invoke(busBundle, null);
                return result != null;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
```

but it returns true

Comment: Hi! Did you already figured out the issue that you were facing? I am currently having the exact same behavior but have no clue what the issue might be?